# Scatter plot on Plotly map but with search bar

Tags: python, plotly

I use Plotly to create scatter plots on maps. Like this for example:

```
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd

geo_df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open(".mapbox_token").read())
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(geo_df,
                        lat=geo_df.geometry.y,
                        lon=geo_df.geometry.x,
                        hover_name="name",
                        zoom=1)
fig.show()
```

https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/

I export it as a HTML file and everything works fine. My question is, can I add a search bar into it to filter locations and export is a HTML file? I want to type Berlin into the search bar and only Berlin should show up.